# Bottle serving images from any UNC path

Tags: bottle, unc

I have an intranet page served through bottle (attached to Apache). How can I display images that are accessible at UNC paths (//server/path/image.gif) ?

My page (and image paths) is generated dynamically from database queries.

Client asks (ajax) to server to display some images based on criteria, server then asks Mongo which replies with arbitrary UNC paths...

If the client can access UNC path from his machine is yet to be decided, but a better solution would be not to rely on this.

This is what I tried or what is not feasible:

1. Tried using a 'file:' protocol:

   ```
   \< img src="file:////server/path/image.gif" >
   ```

   Chrome will not show images failing with a well known error:

   > Not allowed to load local resource

   I do not want to force users to start chrome with flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`
2. Copying images to a  bottle 'static' directory is not really feasible for me

Is there any method I could transfer GIFs from server to client Javascript ? Some kind of jQuery + base64 encoding ?

Not really sure how to tackle this, as web is not my thing :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with and it's working in my situation:

A. I generate all my images setting a default image:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "img/play.png"
```

B. For each image I send an ajax query to bottle requesting specific image encoded as base64. This can be a lot of queries at once, not sure if this is right approach, as I can have as many as 100 images (or more)

C. bottle server loads GIF off disk, encodes to base64 and returns as 'application/json'

D. javascript updates particular image with new base64 data:

```
img.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,' + img_data);
```